# Reviewing First answers: Is a flag enough or should I also leave a comment?

Tags: discussion, review, answers

I was recently awarded privileges to review 'First answers'. I was asked to review an answer that was this:

> Answered and solved by @other_user

And the @other_user had submitted an answer themselves.

Is it then adequate, that I simply flag it as 'Not an answer' - or should I also leave a comment? The user needs to be educated on not to do that again in the future. But is that implicit in the flag - or would it be 'a good service' to also leave a friendly comment?

And is my job as 'First answer'-reviewer, to also consider if that solution is actually an answer?
... To give a practical example: Could someone who's not a brain surgeon review an answer on brain surgery?

---

### Where I looked for the answer

I read the [First answers help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers) - and it is address there, like this:

> One review from a user is enough to dismiss the task so review carefully to ensure that this question meets site expectations. Here are some guidelines when reviewing and deciding which actions to take on new posts:
>
> - Check that the post author attempts to provide a focused answer, and not a simple comment or new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But is that implicit in the flag

Not directly, but a Not An Answer flag puts it in the Low Quality Posts review queue, and users there will be invited to leave a comment. They can even choose from standard ones ('canned comments'):

[image]

That said, I often leave a comment as well. The user script [AutoReviewComments - Pro-forma comments for SE](https://stackapps.com/q/2116/34061) helps me because it's only a couple of clicks, instead of having to type the same comment over and over again.

> And is my job as 'First answer'-reviewer, to also thing if that solution is actually an answer?

Yes. If you're not sure, use the Skip button. [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/4751173).

> To ask it in another way - could someone who's not a brain surgeon review an answer on brain surgery?

That's maybe a bit exaggerated. I think a GP or even a medicine student could review such an answer as well. People with less subject matter expertise will vote on it from outside the review queue as well and we don't stop them either.